# How to make a function return in the parent scope?

Tags: bash

It is annoying to me that `return 0` only works when a file is sourced and when doing a sub-shell you need to `exit 0`. I'm trying to create a function whose code will be evaluated in the parent scope so that it can do:

```
return 0 2>/dev/null
exit 0
```

This is the simplest solution in the parent's scope because if return fails then exit will work & it covers all cases. But it only works of course when coded in the parent scope because a return inside a function scope will obviously return from **just** the function.

How is it possible to do this? I prefer simplicity, but it may not be possible for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is this. Say we want to bail out of a script with exit code 42, whether it is sourced or whether it is run in its own process:

```
return 42 || exit 42
```

I.e. try `return 42`. If that fails, try `exit 42`, which is not expected to fail.

Comment: I suppose it is not possible to combine these commands into say a function or inheritable alias? I'm guessing it is not, so I'm likely to accept your answer I'm just curious.

Comment: Aliases are not inherited via the environment. They can be defined in a `.rc` file, but that's more for personal customization. If I had to write a complex shell application consisting of multiple scripts where I wanted some common aliases, I'd have an environment variable called `foobar_common` (where foobar is the name of my application).  This would hold the absolute path name of a file to be sourced, containing common definitions that are not inheritable.  The top-level script would pass that to other scripts, which would source it using `. "$foobar_common"`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for you help!